# making all subdomains use same document root with nginx

Tags: nginx, domain, virtualhost, domain-name

I have in the *.conf file for my domain the following:

```
server { 
  listen 80; 
  server_name domain.tld; 
  access_log /var/log/nginx/domain.tld.accesslog; 
  root /var/www/domain.tld; 
  index index.htm index.html;
}
```

My question is...  what if I wanted to make all subdomains use the same document root (and same settings in general) as domain.tld?

I tried this:

```
server { 
  listen 80; 
  server_name domain.tld; 
  server_name *.domain.tld; 
  access_log /var/log/nginx/domain.tld.accesslog; 
  root /var/www/domain.tld; 
  index index.htm index.html;
}
```

But that didn't work, even after reloading. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [special syntax](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name) "sugar" to handle this gracefully:

```
server { 
    listen 80; 
    server_name .domain.tld; # ← this one's sweety
    access_log /var/log/nginx/domain.tld.accesslog; 
    root /var/www/domain.tld; 
    index index.htm index.html;
}
```

but in case you're ex-assembler programmer counting CPU-cycles in your spare time, you might want to trade simplicity of shorter notation for [explicit long listing of server's names](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#optimization) (10x2 @[cnst](https://serverfault.com/users/110020/cnst)).

Comment: wrong, `server_name .domain.tld;` is actually the worst way to do this: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Comment: @cnst, lemme correct you: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#optimization )

Comment: I think the whole micro-optimization point here is fairly irrelevant, but how does the link you give correct him at all? It seems to agree with him unless I missed something: `Searching wildcard names hash table is slower than searching exact names hash table because names are searched by domain parts. Note that the special wildcard form “.example.org” is stored in a wildcard names hash table and not in an exact names hash table.`

Comment: @gparent, LOL. It corrects him in a way of supplying link exactly to proper section — mine points to Optimization (which can be considered as another micro-optimization).

Comment: Oh, I see. I saw it after your edit so it was the same link for me here.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>   server_name domain.tld; 
>   server_name *.domain.tld;
> ```

I think the above is the problem.  Try this instead:

```
  server_name domain.tld *.domain.tld;
```

Comment: @ceejayoz, did you read the documentation? seems, that not at all..

quote from http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name 

`server {
    server_name example.com *.example.com www.example.*;
}`

The first two of the above mentioned names can be combined:

`server {
    server_name .example.com;
}`

Comment: @cadmi My only edit was to remove an unnecessary line break. Additionally, "can be" doesn't mean "has to be".

Comment: @ceejayoz why did you have to remove line blank?  there was no problem with the answer, and it was not misformatted in any way, and removing a line blank like that would seem like an unjustified edit

Comment: In my opinion, it's significantly clearer what's happening without the line break - that it's all part of one config directive.

Comment: This is working solution, but rather sub-optimal one comparing to http://serverfault.com/a/493293/67675 and it's not due to an extra-white spaces or font colors.

Comment: @poige, are you kidding me?  did you actually read the docs?  you're basically correct when 100% reversed.  See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html.  Based on the data in the question, there's no way to know what the most optimal solution should actually be.

Comment: @cnst, O_o? In case you mean "optimization" I'd have to agree with you, but what I meant in my turn was optimal way to write it down, do you see the difference?

Comment: @poige, well, what you're doing is imposing your own "cool" optimisation, which might be faster to write, and easier to modify, but it's less intuitive to use, might consumes [slightly] more resources (however insignificant), and is less of a direct response to the actual question;  as such, sorry, but I objectively fail to see why would you categorise this answer as a rather suboptimal one, when it's clearly not

Comment: @cnst, BTW, what d'u think bout `server_name domain.tld .domain.tld;` — it seems to be even more efficient than yours and still shorter. ;-P

Comment: @poige, one symbol shorter?  :-)  And why would it be more efficient?  I still think that `.domain.tld` is something that you have to go look at the manual for, and it doesn't seem to be the preferred way to specify `server_name`, either; so, I really don't care for the `.name` notation!